# 'class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Gui>' has no member named 'emplace'

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, sfml

Hi Guy's looking for some help and can't understand the problem. I'm following this tutorial https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/creating-a-city-building-game-with-sfml-part-8-gui-system/130, I'm using CodeBlocks 13.12 and SFML 2.1 but when I try to compile the code I get this

```
||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\James\Desktop\Summer Repeats 2015\Games Dev 2\Test\src\Game_State_Start.cpp||In constructor 'GameStateStart::GameStateStart(Game*)':|
C:\Users\James\Desktop\Summer Repeats 2015\Games Dev 2\Test\src\Game_State_Start.cpp|100|error: 'class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, Gui>' has no member named 'emplace'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

This is the line of code giving me this error.

```
this->guiSystem.emplace("menu", Gui(sf::Vector2f(192, 32), 4, false, game->stylesheets.at("button"),
    { std::make_pair("Load Game", "load_game") }));
```

I have CodeBlocks set for C++11 and change SFML to SFML-2.3.1-windows-gcc-4.9.2-mingw-32-bit because I found here saying I have to use g++ 4.8.0 or higher on this page [std::map emplace gcc 4.8.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389014/stdmap-emplace-gcc-4-8-2), but still getting the same error, also the website give's me the code to download even though I'm trying to follow it myself , I checked the code, importing into a new project and that didn't work either, So no idea whats wrong. Any help or a point in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Comment: Try creating a really tiny project. `#include <map>` then `int main() { std::map<int,int> m; m.emplace(1,1); }` and nothing else, to see if that compiles or not.

Comment: Didn't work, same error.

Comment: I might of found the error, The version of SFML is higher than 4.8 but I think Codeblocks might only be 4.7.1 after looking routing settings, could be wrong not completely sure with these things as only learning.

Answer (score 4):

Normally I would post this in a comment but I don't have enough rep.
Start a new project and compile and run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << __cplusplus << std::endl;
}
```

If the result printed out is `199711`, then it means you're not compiling using the `-std=c++11` option. If the result printed out is `201101` then it means you're using an outdated version of the standard library.

Comment: Came back as 201103, I take it as i'm up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had originally installed codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup, I uninstalled this and installed codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481. It works now. Thanks for everybody's help.