# How to fix cmGLobalNInjaGenerator.cxx.o" error of cmake?

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-16.04, failed-installation, cmake-modules

I am installing a newer version of cmake which is cmake 3.10.1 and the make command is giving me error while building CXX object source.

I have installed the ninja 1.5.1 but still getting the same error.

used this to install the cmake:

```
wget <link of the cmake3.10.1>
./configure
make # (at this stage getting error)
```

The error is:

```
[ 83%] Building CXX object Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeLib.dir/cmGlobalNinjaGenerator.cxx.o
/media/nadia/967E9B477E9B1F55/data/cmake-3.10.1/Source/cmGlobalNinjaGenerator.cxx: In member function ‘void cmGlobalNinjaGenerator::AppendTargetDependsClosure(const cmGeneratorTarget*, cmNinjaOuts&, bool)’:
/media/nadia/967E9B477E9B1F55/data/cmake-3.10.1/Source/cmGlobalNinjaGenerator.cxx:1077:40: error: ‘class std::map<const cmGeneratorTarget*, std::set<std::basic_string<char> > >’ has no member named ‘emplace_hint’
Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeLib.dir/build.make:5942: recipe for target 'Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeLib.dir/cmGlobalNinjaGenerator.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeLib.dir/cmGlobalNinjaGenerator.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2355: recipe for target 'Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeLib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [Source/CMakeFiles/CMakeLib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389014/stdmap-emplace-gcc-4-8-2 You may need to update your C++ compiler.